# Не проходит push в репозиторий организации в GitHub

Tags: git, github, permissions

Я создатель организации на GitHub В эту организацию я включил команду в которой тоже состою.

Когда мы работаем над общим проектом любые пуши проходят от всех членов команды кроме меня

Права у команды - Администратор

У меня же при попытке пуша в удаленный репозиторий просит заново перелогиниться и затем отклоняет пуш
[image: Скрин]

Но как такое возможно если я создал репозиторий, команду и организацию

Извините если я где то не правильно оформил, но надеюсь мне помогут с настройкой привилегий и доступа меня к моему же гиту.

Comment: У репозитория точно открыт доступ по https? обычно используют ssh и авторизацию по ключу, а не логи/пароль

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, я перепроверю. Клонировал я по HTTPS

Comment: Для работы в репозиториями организации по SSH  требуется премиум) Остальные ребята тоже делали клон по HTTPS и все прекрасно работает. Возможно проблема в том, что у меня этот репозиторий до работы в команде был личный и может быть остальись старые скрытые настройки.

Comment: ¿Может тут происходит попытка авторизоваться со старым токеном?

Comment: Я попробовал сделать пуш даже с другого аккаунта который тоже добавил в команду. Не работает